# Angular file generator like rails scaffold

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there some generator in Angular like in RoR `rails scaffold`?
I want execute one special command and get files, e.g.:

`*.component.html`

`*.component.sass`

`*.component.ts`

`*.module.ts`.

Comment: Fascinating, someone has downvoted three answers all recommending angular-cli, but with no comments to explain the downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, install Angular CLI: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Then you can:

```
ng generate component MyStuff
```

which gives you:

```
my-stuff/my-stuff.component.ts
my-stuff/my-stuff.component.html
my-stuff/my-stuff.component.css
my-stuff/my-stuff.component.spec.ts
```

or:

```
ng generate module MyStuff
```

for:

```
my-stuff/my-stuff.module.ts
```

Angular-cli will also do a bunch of other stuff such as running tests, running a development server, and indeed creating a project from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

`ng generate` (or `ng g`) is the command you are looking for.
For example, to generate new components:

```
ng generate component my-component
```

That command will create a folder called `my-component` and then populate it.

Other commands are:

```
ng generate directive my-directive
ng generate pipe my-pipe
ng generate service my-service
ng generate class my-class
ng generate guard my-guard
ng generate interface my-interface
ng generate enum my-enum
ng generate module my-module
```

More information on all these scaffolding commands can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-components-directives-pipes-and-services).